# Directly use Batch file output as nodejs variable without using txt

Tags: node.js, batch-file

what I'm doing now is make a txt file using batch file output

```
@echo off
set fname=Logan
set lname=Anderson
set gender=male
echo %fname%>>1.txt
echo %lname%>>1.txt
echo %gender%>>1.txt
```

Then read that txt using nodejs and use those as nodejs input, but what I want is
if it is possible to use **batch file output as nodejs input without using this txt file**, directly call **"nodejs compiled project using pkg"** exe file with variables from batch

such as, In batch file

```
@echo off
set fname=Logan
set lname=Anderson
set gender=male
start "" "mycompiledproject.exe" "%fname%" "%lname%" "%gender%"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use command line arguments in node, you need to use process.argv (here is the documentation for it: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

So in your case, your node.js code should look something like this:

```
const process = require('process');

process.argv.forEach(function(value, index, array){
    //value will be the argument(s), index is there position,
    //and array is the entire array they are in. this function 
    //is called for each value.
});
```

once you turn this to exe, it should run in your batch just fine.